# Do not understand Uncaught Typerror Cannot Read Property of 0 Undefinded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Creating my first ReactJS Website and using Node in the back-end, currently in the code that follows I fetch data that I then print on the page. I manage to print the names of the people in a project, their picture and their email from the server BUT the description of the project i get the error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Which I do not understand.

Here is the code :

```
class ProjectPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: [],
        description: [],
        mail: [],
        name: [],
    };
    this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this);
    this.getPictures = this.getPictures.bind(this);
    this.getMails = this.getMails.bind(this);
    this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);
}
```

I create the class and all the elements that are required

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("BEGIN componentDidMount");
    this.fetchDetails();
    this.fetchNames();
    this.fetchMails();
    console.log("END componentDidMount");
}
```

Call all the function in my componentDidMount()

```
fetchDetails() {
    console.log("BEGIN fetchDetails()");

    let url = 'http://192.168.1.33:8080/getprojectdetails/Aprite';
    console.log("url details = " + url);

    fetch(url)
        .then(results => {
            var json = results.json();
            return json;
        })

        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ description: data });
        })

    console.log("END fetchData()");
}
```

Here is the fetch of the project description

```
getDetails = () => {
    let lines = [];
    let nbr = this.state.description.length;
    console.log("nbr = " + nbr);
    if (nbr){
        console.log("lines = " + this.state.description[0].P_Description);
        for (let i = 0; i < nbr; i++)
            lines.push(<div key={this.state.descripton[i].P_Description}></div>);
    }
    return (lines);
}
```

And the function to print the data in the Render() function

But when i try to print this data, the value of nbr passes from 0 to 1 then to 0 again... in the console log I can see the description but it doesn't appear on the website and I don't get it.

Please help me ?

Comment: where is `getDetails` defined? it's arrow function so it don't have `this`.

Comment: it is defined in the constructor where i bind it

Comment: Have you looked at [any of the other questions with that error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+property+%270%27+of+undefined%22)?

Comment: yes i have and it wasn't much help

Comment: The `fetch`es are all async, maybe when you try and access the data the call hasn't completed yet

Comment: no i just had a typo in the GetDetails BUT now that i don't have the error anymore, i don't print anything

Comment: You don't need to bind arrow function, it take no effect since arrow function don't have this, but in this case it don't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the inner loop inside the getDetails function
You should write `this.state.description` not `this.state.descripton`

Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: omg I'm a retard..... thank you .... I don't have the error BUT i don't print anything

Comment: would you put a log inside the then function, where you are setting the description state, to see if the response json is what you think it is

Comment: added a console.log("json= " + json) and it says "json = [object Promise]" in the logs

Comment: No, please log the data inside the next then function after returning JSON (the promise returned from the previous then will resolve before entering the next then and the resolved value will provided)

Comment: solved the problem i just didn't print the data in the GetData... i set it as a key but don't print it in between the opening div tag and closing div tag

Answer (score 0):

So with the React render lifecycle system, the `componentDidMount` will actually happen *after* the first render. During that first render, you're trying to access the first element of an empty array, which is the error you are seeing.

In order to solve this problem, in your render method, you should have a fallback *something* to render while we wait for the `fetchDetails` to return a value from the server. If you want it to render nothing, you can just `return null`.

ie.

```
const { description = [] } = this.state;
if (description.length === 0) {
    return null;
}
return this.getDetails();
```

As a side note, in order to avoid having all of those (which gets pretty unmaintainable):

```
this.getNames = this.getNames.bind(this);
this.getPictures = this.getPictures.bind(this);
this.getMails = this.getMails.bind(this);
this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);
```

You can just define them as class properties like so:

```
getNames = () => {
   // do stuff
}
```